# elasticsearch performance searching single index vs multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch

i am working on API that searches in ElasticSearch. there are multiple index and i need to search for particular field in those indices. Either i can search each index separately and aggregate the output or i can search all indices at once for that field. i am more inclined to search all indices at once as that would make API simpler.

I am not able to figure out what would be the performance degradation if search all indices at once. any one who has done performance test on similar lines, can you please provide feedback or any link to resource which explain about performance would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single search sounds more efficient to me. Keep in mind that indices in Elasticsearch are just an abstract container. The real important part are the number of shards that you searching in.

For Elasticsearch there is no difference if you search in a single index that has 100 shards or if you search in ten indices that have each ten shards. The amount of work that needs to be done, is exactly the same.

Hope that helps!